# TypeError: Cannot read property ‘map’ of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, fullcalendar

I am using angular fullCalendar and I get an error.

**service.ts**

```
getEvents()
  {
    return this.http.get('http:///api/lessons') .map( response => {
      return response.json().data.map((data) => {
            return {...data,start: data.start_time};
          });
   }); 
  }
```

**home.ts**

```
 ngOnInit(){
    this.events = this.service.getEvents().subscribe(events => {this.events = events;});
}
```

I faced this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property ‘map’ of undefined

Comment: Can you create an example on stackblitz.com My guess is you do not need `response.json()`

Comment: Does the response contain data?

Comment: @wentjun, please don't add tags that the question doesn't involve. The fact that you suggest the use of RxJs as solution doesn't make the question proper to be under that tag. The OP uses regular JS .map in their question

Answer (score 2):

You should be using RxJS's [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) operator. Please take note that it is different from JavaScript's [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

In addition, for RxJS 6+, you should be using [pipeable operators](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#operators), hence the usage of the `pipe()` function.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

getEvents() {
  return this.http.get('http:///api/lessons') 
    .pipe(
      map(response => {
        return response.map((data) => {
          return {...data,start: data.start_time};
        });
     })
  ); 
}
```

In addition, on your component.ts, the `console.log()` statement should be handled within `subscribe()`, as HTTP requests are asynchronous in nature. Placing it outside will result in it being displayed as `undefined`.

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.service.getEvents().subscribe(events => {
    this.events = events;
    console.log(this.events);
  });
}
```

Comment: still ı am getting same error please help me

Comment: @B.T hey, I have made a change to my answer. I made an error. Refer to the line with `return response.map`.. It should solve your problem! Let me know if it works

Comment: ı have this error   TypeError: response.map is not a function.

Comment: I think thats because of ı am using two map

Comment: but ı have to use two map what should ı do please help me

Comment: and ı will post image as answer  below  where ı am get error

Comment: ı have error about second map which ı used response.map is not function

Comment: @B.T Hmmm.. Can you try and `console.log(response)` and see what it prints out?

Comment: like this   Response {_body: "[{"id":2,"lesson_id":5,"author":30,"teacher_id":30…","jurisdiction":3,"delete":0,"api_token":null}}]", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, …}

Comment: @B.T You can try return `response._body.map(.....`. That is because the result array is nested within `_body`

Answer (score 1):

looks like You're using an old http,
please update to HttpClient, so You will not need

```
`return response.json().data.map((data) => {
        return {...data,start: data.start_time};
      });`
```

just `return response(data => {
            return {...data,start: data.start_time};
          });`

Comment: ı used your suggestion but its give syntax error

Comment: sorry, it was pseudo, but please use this one as an example https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#http-request-example